# Reduce space between raincloud facets and plot all stat_dots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm visualizing the durations of gazes to co-participants across two conditions ("with IGA" and "without IGA") in two raincloud plots. However, the way I'm doing it leaves too much space between the two facets. Also, where the durations are particularly dense (around 1 in the "without IGA" condition) it seems that only a fraction of the stat_dots are shown (**NB**: based on the small sample data posted here, all stat_dots *are* visible; in the actual data, which comprise many thousand observations, many of them seem to be cut off)

How can the **space between the two facets be reduced** and how can **all stat_dots be plotted**?

```
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("tidyquant")
library(tidyquant)
#install.packages("ggdist")
library(ggdist)
#install.packages("ggthemes")
library(ggthemes)

df %>%
  # plot:
  ggplot(
    
    # Proportional Durations:
    aes(x = IGA, y = AOI_prop_in_Turn, fill = IGA)) +
  
  stat_dots(
    aes(
      justification = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", 1.2, -.2),
      side = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", "left", "right"),
    ),
    # adjust grouping (binning) of observations
    binwidth = 0.005
  ) +
  
  # add half-violin from {ggdist} package:
  stat_halfeye(
    aes(
      # adjust positioning:
      justification = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", 1.2, -.2),
      side = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", "left", "right"),
    ),
    # adjust bandwidth:
    adjust = 1.2,
    # remove the slub interval:
    .width = 0,
    point_colour = NA
  ) +
  
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.2,
    notch = TRUE,
    alpha = 0.25
  ) +
  
  labs(
    title = "Durations of Speakers' Gazes to Co-participants\n(proportional to duration of turn)",
    x = "Turns",
    y = "Proportional durations"
  ) +
  theme_blank() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(IGA = c("without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "with IGA", 
"without IGA", "with IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", "without IGA", 
"without IGA"), AOI_prop_in_Turn = c(0.0931840632202832, 0.00103883152230371, 
0.00277357539082199, 0.169645203679369, 0.0188323917137476, 0.0172183464450052, 
0.914781693845345, 0.742857142857143, 0.00589071704245379, 0.424731182795699, 
1, 1, 0.169017632241814, 0.401394133023526, 0.0410531660259665, 
0.0204049599748862, 0.062751971954426, 0.266272189349112, 0.463993453355155, 
0.142982938910292, 0.0128073770491803, 0.0032979976442874, 0.336764705882353, 
0.0646113044919609, 0.340140845070423, 0.00414334520607691, 0.0112571745972968, 
0.00364170713007922, 0.00570054945054945, 0.00551181102362205, 
0.196386946386946, 0.282424242424242, 0.0479885057471264, 0.143752515669024, 
0.0187306292952432, 0.0211143695014663, 0.00029087282624504, 
0.0583812472357364, 0.814814814814815, 0.677551020408163, 0.0403321470937129, 
0.552402290266368, 0.21840242669363, 0.074929369856283, 0.0431617264690588, 
0.0175803958144348, 0.0815919037199125, 0.054356846473029, 0.0571791613722999, 
0.222388059701493, 0.675, 0.0072936012156002, 0.0294787449392713, 
0.0810410495133305, 0.0589756854630109, 0.0718232044198895, 0.48991083998123, 
0.0103097345132743, 0.00815516861362134, 0.0159181131781739, 
0.003890209639075, 0.190058479532164, 0.00704070407040704, 0.0261871312166339, 
0.0945467422096317, 0.0104127326679255, 0.21500630517024, 0.0630252100840336, 
0.122941597627084, 0.107661194384963, 0.00293321299638989, 0.0143760520449479, 
0.0205829249419654, 0.0175879396984925, 1, 0.100233595243151, 
0.265060240963855, 0.170138888888889, 0.0232845026985351, 0.0134388889720298, 
0.0333535476046089, 0.00110080201289511, 0.710179640718563, 1, 
0.0150122945515724, 0.254545454545455, 0.238527724665392, 1.00000000000058, 
0.0136746046970486, 0.0386143657666836, 0.0732560463721767, 0.863110612015721, 
0.0123936503259548, 0.230647709320695, 0.0124835330280409, 0.180519897304236, 
0.037337516808606, 0.549492385786802, 0.310178817056396, 0.128723404255319, 
0.0026279116066096, 0.0817788141239174, 0.0305343511450382, 0.00547580287109664, 
0.307241746538871, 0.337748344370861, 0.727878787878995, 0.76218611521418, 
0.22550831792976, 0.0098500277726347, 0.0193844955200623, 0.00612485276796231, 
0.0618218161050828, 0.00791412932729901, 1, 0.0735829433177327, 
0.0814268142681427, 1, 0.0396593223477134, 0.2218945487042, 0.439073112265282, 
0.136766975308642, 0.0455681818181818, 0.458665033680343, 0.0794438927507448, 
0.0357348229688655, 0.025631067961165, 0.220410310362967, 1, 
0.0817813765182186, 0.156547619047619, 0.00187207488299532, 0.16089273817455, 
1, 0.292682926829268, 0.159036144578313, 0.0253997499506482, 
0.310344827586207, 0.0061354849554547, 0.396580188679245, 0.000812512695510867, 
0.00646065229236398, 0.083356070941337, 0.233972859148339, 0.235748218527316, 
0.0279551879384358, 0.843706777316736, 0.855194123819517, 0.0101373446697188, 
0.011986301369863, 0.0745098039215686, 0.0853052877592755, 0.0129807692307692, 
0.00839988983751033, 0.00677251862442622, 0.0185742315238718, 
0.0634590722150975, 0.00267952840300107, 0.155237154150198, 0.0243492863140218, 
0.465671641791045, 0.0623441396508728, 0.070048821906177, 0.00368570055018428, 
0.0113732692851088, 0.257023933402706, 0.155031731640979, 0.0573673870333988, 
0.0725689404934688, 0.00325837295016292, 0.077861406696081, 0.00655451168887918, 
0.0640429338103757, 0.187211417377921, 1, 0.408333333333333, 
0.0193260654112983, 0.295, 0.0547836684948202, 0.0249958561246478, 
0.00232883092687471, 0.354794520547945, 1, 0.141912341665733, 
0.0225035161744023, 0.0120313527735146, 1, 1, 0.47244094488189, 
0.025857654889913, 0.00753107703475184, 0.49, 0.0175412067140481, 
0.110824028790256, 0.20952380952381, 0.00335172834072519, 0.00660670222080713, 
0.118320610687023, 0.471856036827788, 0.979518072289157, 0.00384489350081922, 
0.0498392282958199, 0.0436141600639674, 0.00471102885505174, 
0.0493525790702611, 0.214342313787639, 0.00304617849030344, 0.127841967946329, 
0.109537299338999, 0.783495145631068, 1, 0.367253521126761, 0.136136136136136, 
0.0919504960621868, 0.181395348837209, 0.0240802946294872, 0.00467744467116622, 
0.239065180102916, 0.118985302999799, 0.0483543275091426, 0.969596001665972, 
0.0336417157275021, 0.0327077747989276, 0.319144981412639, 1, 
1, 0.00273146839973627, 0.00534526017235737, 0.376494023904382, 
0.12585969738652, 0.0433833390512429, 1, 0.0215277522006556, 
0.177700348432056, 0.0712666834550491, 0.0310018903591682, 0.389112903225806, 
0.0115946078088985, 0.0452674897119342, 0.00220607318972229, 
0.0573499491353001, 0.0394758666445513, 0.0233877038895859, 0.100836012861736, 
0.0131465517241379, 0.140036563071298, 0.415026833631485, 0.0103876185164529, 
0.156152125279642, 0.549215882549216, 0.214215080346106, 0.0207813798836243, 
1, 0.858943286476006, 0.021624073794042, 0.0160771704180064, 
0.0039112501777841, 0.18658365133561, 0.00718205590954293, 0.0114293583034977, 
0.0149918053998102, 0.0349348501351406, 0.0416275919558197, 0.164355267040425, 
0.0599850968703428, 1, 0.00312174817898023, 0.00891976692066338, 
0.0145471720392018, 0.327519379844961, 0.24188790560472, 0.139304655274013, 
0.952755905511811, 0.262019230769231, 0.552380952380952, 0.13617677286742, 
0.710731707317073, 0.000862068965517241, 1.00000000000026, 0.0435290680689454, 
0.00413827437070226, 0.00604381767816671, 0.0723522853957637, 
0.576871657754011, 0.180952380952381, 0.0501062322946176, 1, 
1, 0.0255591054313099, 0.175516917293233, 0.0757104060409353, 
1.00000000000069, 0.0274086378737542, 0.0916206261510129, 0.184952978056426, 
0.0325799573560768, 0.00464459438255139, 0.188636363636364, 0.22682119205298, 
0.00888888888888889, 0.0123352215575202, 0.0540792540792541, 
0.0518605131026893, 0.0365568544102019, 0.625806451612903, 0.00393912264995524, 
0.242424242424242, 0.0123690306675451, 0.850828729281768, 0.554156171284635, 
0.239583333333333, 0.0185805665549802, 0.321138211382114, 0.140709459459459, 
0.0123394610929237, 0.0169544740973312, 0.23695652173913, 0.0247805665951161, 
0.00841006307547307, 0.0442411996171435, 0.0229323308270677, 
0.0116667072606377, 0.00395901257568701, 0.0491803278688525, 
0.109422139707589, 0.647161572052402, 1, 0.288090485695276, 0.0227272727272727, 
0.0366, 0.0826243877287961, 0.0401937046004843, 0.0347937048064653, 
0.0347099926148952, 0.0361851533390656, 0.341463414634146, 0.0368611670020121, 
0.046686551679419, 1, 0.00353207120655552, 0.288423806409418, 
0.053276505061268, 0.164588528678304, 0.0293369663941871, 0.00914770191878626, 
0.0147255689424364, 0.24047619047619, 0.107247796278171, 0.21084704448507, 
0.0313767342582711, 0.455647734524569, 0.0942896037830479, 0.0442355117139341, 
0.0199814986123959, 0.0037037037037037, 1, 0.999999999999933, 
0.0168815224063843, 0.00638316225308374, 0.00873968492123031, 
0.353396388650043, 0.017816091954023, 0.0522688110281447, 0.012407063197026, 
0.211362248014661, 0.0528072635022365, 0.0134519418528965, 0.00478015716801586, 
0.0256308206638542, 0.416129032258065, 0.067935368043088, 0.0975839717147908, 
0.0811933752668936, 0.0252494624841502, 0.267626430417128, 0.178061224489796, 
0.637619553666312, 0.202, 0.210601719197778, 0.0165123456790123, 
0.0127566383794142, 0.0551816958277254, 1, 0.0599846193283773, 
0.0589420654911839, 0.00895367894419043, 0.0317271646703849, 
1, 0.266912142490152, 0.454377880184332, 0.845161290322739, 0.10183299389002, 
0.143623361144219, 0.06875, 0.163678877630553, 0.113441575725313, 
0.091419893697798, 0.215384615384615, 0.0605882352941176, 0.0814024390243902, 
0.00364150054936431, 0.24727016555125, 0.125602074842534, 0.00775691286029186, 
0.00406967834215948, 0.00233707865168539, 0.197860024557095, 
0.0575, 1, 0.988888888888889, 0.503267973856209, 0.285229202037354, 
0.0240362811791383, 0.910869565217391, 0.935074626865672, 0.00621062240912288, 
0.0263507949578767, 0.023527554081794, 0.0461275993047061, 0.580952380952381, 
1, 0.00900562851782364, 0.0174644243208279, 0.128324567993989, 
1, 1, 0.083, 0.241127065835817, 1, 0.884563758389262, 0.702623906705539, 
0.871817004747518, 0.26517571884984, 0.873575129533679, 0.58768115942029, 
0.973584905660377, 0.00336190956463271, 0.00776483638380477, 
0.311393489434609, 0.0275632288353779, 0.284444444444444, 0.0938931297709924, 
0.00168875337164302, 0.0100920638620207, 1, 0.0630950869620414, 
0.0489236790606654, 0.0271279243404679, 0.712655086848635, 0.0400424290639088, 
1, 0.014109926168991, 0.182680901542112, 0.00701754385964912, 
0.136111689935403, 0.00745274689094746, 0.0322441030080069, 0.132315521628499, 
0.00991407799074686, 0.0612546125461255, 0.872835150737652, 0.00398680230959582, 
0.0220301171221417, 0.00806112208229467, 0.00965592572364828, 
0.0501056444310293, 0.140298784448362, 0.0313683071930773, 0.0657237052004679, 
0.0116717635066259, 0.832307692307692, 0.00451284424901643, 0.165932452276065, 
1, 0.203393939393939, 0.103249097472924, 0.0263772954924875, 
0.00364150054936431, 0.0698689956331878, 0.0334948935433616, 
0.013953488372093, 0.0364907292222025, 0.924812030075188, 1, 
0.193865030674847, 0.0103675777568332, 0.00248832013000203, 0.0105630026809651, 
0.0235119047619048, 0.0142797232124135, 0.166938490214352, 0.12851711026616, 
0.0048409548939353, 0.0109845402766477, 0.0163185378590078, 0.00825459970164097, 
0.026665598975016, 1, 0.171309192200557, 0.0143554407120299, 
0.10836038961039, 0.0100527770796683, 1, 0.0653714885796797, 
0.00739755631285845, 0.0257022471910112, 0.0986310016964532, 
0.0239744272775706, 1, 0.096137339055794, 0.00466858628497945, 
0.04832995951417, 0.251219512195122, 0.00254723546171925, 0.00860655737704918, 
0.391389432485323, 1, 0.0638586956521739, 0.0577836287554657, 
1, 0.375820056232427, 1, 0.000265014741444993, 0.231818181818182, 
0.045785324439054, 0.686187845303867, 0.814465408805031, 0.0460567823343849, 
1, 0.00779363477238754, 0.0450717049852037, 0.00726999247931812, 
0.0138424164642251, 0.149279322724107, 0.0165940790561773, 0.0826815082230245, 
0.713804713804714, 0.197287134031695, 0.0200538358008075, 0.0126218404097142, 
1, 0.0198019801980198, 0.00644821687064087, 0.0649960845732185, 
0.38016038016038, 0.104895104895105, 0.00617927337701013, 0.439699485962831, 
0.0499935408861904, 0.0264220183486237, 0.0671031856598867, 0.232, 
0.203631185475258, 0.0466760961810467, 0.093569844789357, 0.416507936507936, 
0.0559352517985612, 0.123789020452099, 0.138095238095238, 0.328695652173913, 
0.183012670107931, 0.0538542766631468, 0.0746113989637306, 0.0280968468468468, 
0.383050847457627, 0.020789138735681, 0.105494505494505, 0.0190426091530773, 
1, 0.0708374384236453, 0.0260598503740648, 0.0131818181818182, 
0.0108910167385425, 0.0115811112076204, 1, 0.0157257430413587, 
0.0417905102954342, 0.050192404216162, 0.0246513439813011, 0.0602272727272727, 
0.0102902893069404, 0.0104138120032886, 0.0414043583535109, 0.999287749287749, 
0.235395189003436, 1, 1, 0.0652624860379767, 0.0642016806722689, 
0.322773352643012, 0.0242172211350294, 0.720869565217391, 0.0220588235293929, 
0.07289668402302, 0.0283503389714442, 0.0108785458551363, 0.0164319248826291, 
0.701951507983442, 0.443029917250159, 0.0137115839243499, 0.0358195672729295, 
1, 0.0404933674656737, 0.827272727272727, 0.0990608228980349, 
1, 0.85, 0.00127413896078041, 0.0104703736019672, 0.0402707275803722, 
0.02098085496984, 0.478274760383387, 1, 0.0630434782608696, 0.0104288989543142, 
0.0205070422535211, 0.02250665132667, 1, 0.165044247787611, 0.233269165439928, 
0.0536608408124705, 0.042982971227246, 0.458502024291498, 0.00222554850907945, 
0.498162729658793, 0.154620311070448, 0.674672489082969, 0.00424962160903481, 
0.00308271964377462, 0.0549019607843137, 0.00850324586266801, 
1, 1, 0.0349863097048981, 0.465968586387378, 1, 0.266521197007481, 
0.019145412388208, 0.0111703305123708, 0.107292355144305, 1, 
0.226264418811003, 0.481335952848723, 0.0446739382687398, 0.0707174231332357, 
0.427522935779817, 0.0381362958050075, 0.382978723404255, 0.081203007518797, 
0.22093023255814, 1, 0.00487012987012987, 0.0871391076115486, 
0.424738219895288, 1, 1, 0.000364395269486865, 0.107011070110701, 
0.0438000302069174, 0.00440908337477209, 0.102227298686465, 0.0431208053691275, 
0.00511811956495984, 0.0305184162856895, 0.681290322580645, 0.059743824336688, 
0.0403496973772697, 0.00558774834437086, 0.755498059508409, 0.179782903663501, 
0.00319532820978982, 0.3203125, 0.568571428571429, 0.0779296875, 
0.237333333333333, 1, 0.00068562880472045, 0.107597623089983, 
0.0274853233710155, 0.633507853403141, 0.0189640035118525, 1, 
0.39439342677622, 0.031496062992126, 0.672794117647059, 0.294014084507042, 
0.0249793093070499, 0.115467367917762, 0.776166209329675, 0.417730496453901, 
0.22964509394572, 0.00343241911643948, 0.00458589379069981, 0.173695198329854, 
0.0437749452813184, 0.0120095715382184, 0.00363297624592455, 
0.035377358490566, 0.0304789550072569, 0.117391304347826)), row.names = c(NA, 
-700L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll tackle these issues in turn.

##### 1. How to make sure all the dots are plotted?

Unfortunately there are tutorials out there for raincloud plots using `ggdist::geom_dots()` that tell people to manually set the `binwidth`. Yet, one of the main reasons `ggdist::geom_dots()` exists as an alternative to `ggplot2::geom_dotplot()` is to make it so that you *don't* have to manually set the `binwidth`!

If you manually set the `binwidth`, there is no guarantee the dots can fit in the display. But if you don't provide a `binwidth`, `ggdist::geom_dots()` will pick a `binwidth` for you that ensures everything fits.

To demonstrate, I've taken your example code and made a few changes so things are easier to see:

1. I've removed the `stat_halfeye()` layer, since it was being drawn over the dots (I'm not sure if there was something else you wanted to do with the density plots?).
2. I've set `linewidth = 0` on `geom_dots()` to remove the gray outline around the dots so that the fill color is actually visible.

As a minor note, I am also using `geom_dots()` instead of `stat_dots()` here; both will do the same thing in this case, but when you're just plotting sample data `geom_dots()` typically makes more sense (the extra features of `stat_dots()` are really only useful for analytical distributions).

This automatically picks an appropriate `binwidth` (i.e. dot size) so that everything fits:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = IGA, y = AOI_prop_in_Turn, fill = IGA)) +
  geom_dots(
    aes(
      justification = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", 1.2, -.2),
      side = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", "left", "right"),
    ),
    # set linewidth = 0 to remove the gray outline around dots
    # so we can see the dot fill color
    linewidth = 0,
    # if you DO NOT set binwidth here, geom_dots() will automatically
    # pick a binwidth so that everything fits
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.2,
    notch = TRUE,
    alpha = 0.25
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Durations of Speakers' Gazes to Co-participants\n(proportional to duration of turn)",
    x = "Turns",
    y = "Proportional durations"
  ) +
  # not sure what package theme_blank() came from so I'll just use theme_ggdist() here
  theme_ggdist() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: raincloud plots of two groups, consisting of a boxplot and a dotplot each]

To demonstrate the problem with setting `binwidth` manually, let's instead set the `binwidth` to `0.02`:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = IGA, y = AOI_prop_in_Turn, fill = IGA)) +
  geom_dots(
    aes(
      justification = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", 1.2, -.2),
      side = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", "left", "right"),
    ),
    linewidth = 0,
    # if you set the binwidth manually, there is no guarantee 
    # all the dots will fit
    binwidth = 0.02,
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.2,
    notch = TRUE,
    alpha = 0.25
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Durations of Speakers' Gazes to Co-participants\n(proportional to duration of turn)",
    x = "Turns",
    y = "Proportional durations"
  ) +
  theme_ggdist() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: raincloud plots with manual binwidth: some stacks of dots are too tall and go off the edge of the chart]

Notice how the manually-set larger `binwidth` forces some stacks of dots to be too tall, so they go off the plot edge. If you do want to set the `binwidth` manually (maybe the dot size gets too small, or you have some meaningful data resolution for your domain at which you want to be able to see specific values), you can use the `overflow = "compress"` option. This will keep the specified `binwidth` and, if the dots would overrun the plot area, instead compress the spacing between dots to prevent this. This is best combined with some transparency so the overlaps are visible. For example:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = IGA, y = AOI_prop_in_Turn, fill = IGA)) +
  geom_dots(
    aes(
      justification = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", 1.2, -.2),
      side = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", "left", "right"),
    ),
    linewidth = 0,
    # set the binwidth manually, but compress the dot spacing
    # in the presence of overflow (plus alpha to make it 
    # easier to see overlapping dots)
    binwidth = 0.02,
    overflow = "compress",
    alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.2,
    notch = TRUE,
    alpha = 0.25
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Durations of Speakers' Gazes to Co-participants\n(proportional to duration of turn)",
    x = "Turns",
    y = "Proportional durations"
  ) +
  theme_ggdist() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: dotplots with a larger binwidth than before, but compressed so that dots overlap somewhat]

##### 2. How to reduce the space between the categories?

You asked how to reduce the space between the facets, which I take to mean the categories on the *x* axis (strictly speaking these are not facets in ggplot lingo, because facets are not categorical x axis mappings, they are separate panels created by faceting commands like `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()`).

The spacing here is determined by the *x* axis limits: the wider the limits, the less space there will be between categories. So you could just increase the x axis limits using `coord_cartesian()`:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = IGA, y = AOI_prop_in_Turn, fill = IGA)) +
  geom_dots(
    aes(
      justification = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", 1.2, -.2),
      side = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", "left", "right"),
    ),
    linewidth = 0
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.2,
    notch = TRUE,
    alpha = 0.25
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Durations of Speakers' Gazes to Co-participants\n(proportional to duration of turn)",
    x = "Turns",
    y = "Proportional durations"
  ) +
  theme_ggdist() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1, 4))
```

[image: raincloud plots that are closer together (but also smaller) because of large x axis limits]

However, this solution is kind of unsatisfying because you don't make use of the extra space. Another option would be to increase the width of the dotplots to something greater than 1, which would automatically increase the axis limits while also taking up the extra space:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = IGA, y = AOI_prop_in_Turn, fill = IGA)) +
  geom_dots(
    aes(
      justification = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", 1.2, -.2),
      side = ifelse(IGA == "with IGA", "left", "right"),
    ),
    linewidth = 0,
    # increase the width of the dotplots
    width = 3
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(
    # also increase the width of the boxplot accordingly
    width = 0.6,
    notch = TRUE,
    alpha = 0.25
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Durations of Speakers' Gazes to Co-participants\n(proportional to duration of turn)",
    x = "Turns",
    y = "Proportional durations"
  ) +
  theme_ggdist() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: raincloud plots with less space between them, but also with dotplots taking up the extra space]

Notice how, since I have left off specifying `binwidth`, `geom_dots()` automatically picks an appropriate binwidth here for everything to fit. Saves me fiddling with binwidths. For more on `geom_dots()` options, see the [dotsinterval vignette](https://mjskay.github.io/ggdist/articles/dotsinterval.html).